# Connecting R To Teradata VOLATILE TABLE

Tags: r, teradata, volatile, rodbc

I am using R to try and connect to a teradata database and am running into difficulties
The steps in the process are below

1)  Create Connection
2)  Create a VOLATILE TABLE
3)  Load information from a data frame into the Volatile table

Here is where it fails, giving me an error message

**Error in sqlSave(conn, mydata, tablename = "TEMP", rownames = FALSE,  : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel**

The code is below

```
# Import Data From Text File and remove duplicates
mydata = read.table("Keys.txt")
mydata.unique = unique(mydata)

strSQL.TempTable = "CREATE VOLATILE TABLE TEMP………[Table Details]"
    "UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(index)"
    "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;"

 # Connect To Database
   conn <- tdConnect('Teradata')

 # Execute Temp Table
   tdQuery(strSQL.TempTable)
   sqlSave(conn, mydata, tablename = "TEMP ",rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

Can anyone help, Is it closing off the connection before I can upload the information into the Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Mistake, I have been confusing libraries

Basically the lines

```
 # Connect To Database
   conn <- tdConnect('Teradata')

 # Execute Temp Table
   tdQuery(strSQL.TempTable)
   sqlSave(conn, mydata, tablename = "TEMP ",rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

can all be replaced by this

```
# Connect To Database
channel <- odbcConnect('Teradata')
# Execute Temp Table
sqlQuery(channel, paste(strSQL.TempTable))

sqlSave(channel, mydata, table = "TEMP",rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

Now I'm being told, i don't have access to do this but this is another question for another forum

Thanks