# R Teradata volatile table with ROBDC

Tags: r, teradata, rodbc

I have been trying to figure out how to write a data frame to a volatile table on a teradata server. I was trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499959/connecting-r-to-teradata-volatile-table) but am not having a lot of luck.

Here's my attempt:

```
pass = getPass(msg = "Network Password:")
edv = odbcConnect(dsn = "", uid = "", pwd = pass)
rm(pass)

# So I believe we'll first have to create a table:
quer1 = paste("CREATE VOLATILE TABLE testdat",
               "(op_sys INT, enter_final_icu VARCHAR(20), mrn VARCHAR(8))",
               "UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(op_sys)",
               "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;")
sqlQuery(edv, quer1)

# This returns a zero row table, so far so good:
quer2 = "select top 10 * from testdat"
sqlQuery(edv, quer2)

# See if we can save the data:
columnTypes <- list(op_sys = "INT", 
                    enter_final_icu = "VARCHAR(20)", 
                    mrn = "VARCHAR(8)")
# pop is a data.frame with 3 the same 3 columns as in the definition of testdat
sqlSave(channel = edv, 
        dat = pop, 
        tablename = 'testdat', 
        append = TRUE, 
        rownames = FALSE, 
        varTypes = columnTypes)


sqlUpdate(channel = edv, 
        dat = pop, 
        tablename = 'testdat')
```

The `sqlSave` statement tells me that 'table testdat already exists' which is what I thought I wanted to do. I thought `update = TRUE` would let me add data to the table...

The `sqlUpdate` statement tells me that 'testdat: table not found' which is pretty odd given that I'm able to query it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It might be due to the temporary status of volatile tables. Try running your `sqlSave` directly after your `sqlQuery` that runs `CREATE`.

Comment: In brief experiments with R and Teradata, I've never had much success with volatile tables.  I hit the same error with sqlSave you do.  Works fine with permanent tables.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess since I don't know how R determines if the volatile table exists (in order to determine if the table needs to be created or not). It *COULD* be that R is relying on the default database of the ODBC connection in Teradata to qualify your unqualified table name. For fun, try setting your `tablename` of your `sqlsave` command to the username you are using to connect appending `.testdat` to it. So if your username in Teradata `bobmcbob` then `tablename = 'bobmcbob.testdat',`

Comment: @JNevill - I've tried it with `my_id.volatile_table_name` and `volatile_table_name`.  No difference in behavior, fails with the same error for both.

Comment: Darn. Thought we may get lucky with that one. It's strange that it thinks it doesn't exist. I'd vlbe very curious to know how it's assessing that under the covers.

Comment: BTW, looking at the link the OP posted, it looks like that was done using a package called teradataR, which doesn't seem to exist in the cran repositories.  Looks like you can download it from GitHub, proceed at your own risk, your mileage may vary, etc...